# Updating DataBase via Datagridview and OleDbDataAdapter and met if an exception

Tags: c#, database, winforms, ms-access

I have a Datagridview and it has a table already connected via OleDbDataAdapter. Whenever I try to the value of a certain cell I want it to be updated at my DataBase. I'm met with an exception: "Update requires a valid UpdateCommand when passed DataRow collection with modified rows."
So I think I should add an UpdateCommand?

```
        private void workersPicBox_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {

            workersView.Location = new Point(82, 91);
            workersView.Size = new Size(719, 355);


            clickedID = idWorkersDB;
            DBpanel.Visible = true;
            DBpanel.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;

            titleDataLbl.Text = "Worker's Data";
            titleDataLbl.Left = (this.Width - titleDataLbl.Width) / 2;

            OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Users\myname\Downloads\loginDataCopyyy.mdb");
            OleDbDataAdapter cmd = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM workers", con);
            con.Open();
            DataTable tbl = new DataTable();
            cmd.Fill(tbl);
            con.Close();

            workersView.DataSource = tbl;
            
            if (workersView != null)
            {
                this.Controls.Add(workersView);
                workersView.CellValueChanged += new DataGridViewCellEventHandler(WorkersViewSendDataToDB);
            }
            
            

            workersView.Show();
            workersView.BringToFront();
        }
        private void WorkersViewSendDataToDB(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            using (OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Users\myname\Downloads\loginDataCopyyy.mdb"))
            {
                OleDbDataAdapter adap = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM workers", con);

                con.Open();
                DataTable tempTable = new DataTable();       
                adap.Update((DataTable)workersView.DataSource); // the problem is here ;)        
                con.Close();
            }
```

As you can see I've tried running adap.Update((DataTable)workersView.DataSource);
I was expecting it to update the DataBase with the value that I've changed in the cell in the Datagridview. After that I met the execption that I've mentioned above.
Yes I have a primary key inside my table.
But my real question is: I need to create a UpdateCommand to have my database updated but what should I write there?

What should I do?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have no `UPDATE` queries there, nor a CommandBuilder. You should read: [Updating Data Sources with DataAdapters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/updating-data-sources-with-dataadapters)

Comment: Hi :) thank you very much. I read this article and it helped me as I've used OleDbCommandBuilder()